How can I animating elements between screens with expo router
I am pretty new to expo and react native in general and want to make an animation, that goes from my profile screen to my detail screen seamlessly.
I found that sharedTransitionTags are used for this things but when tried implementing it looks like this:
How my transition looks like
the structure of the Animated.View is the same except the height.
<Animated.View
          style={{ width: widthOutfitCard, height: heightOutfitRow }}
          sharedTransitionTag={"outfit-detail-" + outfit.id}
          sharedTransitionStyle={customTransition}
></Animated.View>

tried using the sample animation from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/shared-element-transitions/
const customTransition = SharedTransition.custom((values) => {
  'worklet';
  return {
    height: withSpring(values.targetHeight),
    width: withSpring(values.targetWidth),
    originX: withSpring(values.targetOriginX),
    originY: withSpring(values.targetOriginY),
  };
});

but this didn't work as expected.
I would like to have a animation like Instagram. where it looks like the site isn't changing.
Hope you understand my problem and you know how to fix it :).
